# Is the ^ (starts with caret) relative to the .htaccess file or relative to the site root?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

if I have an `.htaccess` file on my site located at `example.com/folder1/folder2/.htaccess`

and I want to write a rule that effects a page at `example.com/folder1/folder2/page.php`

Would i need to make the rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ page/
```

Or as

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/page\.php$ page/
```

Basically is the `^` (starts with) relative to the `.htaccess` file or relative to the site root?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on your [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

So with `RewriteBase /`, `^` is relative to web root. In which case you would need `^folder1/folder2/page.php`